# Date format returned as timestamp in response instead of format yyyy-mm-dd SpringBoot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, rest, date, response

I have a SpringBoot app connected to a PostgreSQL database. I have an entity, a person and the person has a birthdate. The way I defined the birthdate in the entity is:

```
    @Column(name="birth_date", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    private Date birthDate;
```

I'm using java.util.Date. I have a DTO, a service and a controller (I use REST API). The DTO objects are formed correctly. When I try to execute a query to get all the persons the birthdate is displayed as timestamp in Postman:

```
 {
    "name": "Mary",
        "birthDate": 539301600000,
        "gender": "female"
}
```

Do you have an idea what can be the cause? Thank you!

Comment: use `LocalDate` instead of `util.Date`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonformat annotation.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date birthDate;
```

For more information about JSON format check [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates)